# Linking to subpage using iframe

Tags: iframe, hyperlink, parent

Am trying to link to a specific iframe subpage and have it open in the parent page.
Destination iframe is on a separate url from links.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Does target=_top on your href tag solve your problem?